# How to programmatically add tooltip to a combobox

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to add a tip to a `combobox` during runtime with the code below but it doesn't work:

```
onStartReport: function (aButton) {
    var lTip = Ext.getCmp('datasources');
    lTip.setTooltip("Information on datasource");
}
```

I also tried with this, but I get an error:

```
onStartReport: function (aButton) {
     var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
     target: 'datasources',
     html: 'Information on datasource'
     });        
}
```

view classic:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    itemId: 'datasources',
    name: 'datasources',
    fieldLabel: 'Data sources',
    displayField: 'description',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',
    value: 0,
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,   
    store: {
        data: [
            {id: 0, description: 'OnLine'},
            {id: 1, description: 'History'}
        ],
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'description', type: 'string'}               
        ],
        autoLoad: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.Create some fiddle and show your issue there.

Answer (score 1):

This method should be fine:

```
onStartReport: function (aButton) {
    var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: 'datasources',
        html: 'Information on datasource'
});
```

The problem is that your component doesn't really have an `id`, the only config you added was `itemId` and they are not quite the same, see the documentation. This is also why `Ext.getCmp('datasources')` is not working.

One way to fix this is to simply change `itemId` to `id` and the reference will be found.

If you don't want to add an id to your component, and keep using itemId, you could use the code below:

```
onStartReport: function (aButton) {
    var combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datasources')[0],
        tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: combo.el,
        html: 'Information on datasource'
});
```

There is also a third option which is to grab the combobox in it's relation to the component/controller that is calling the `onStartReport` method.
I have added an example here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hap

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!